# CMD ignore or compare the newline character

Tags: command

Code:

```
For /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('wmic memorychip get capacity') do (
        echo [%%i]>>c:\info.txt
)
```

Output:

```
[Capacity]
[8589934592]
[
]
```

At the last line you see the bracket with the newline character in it. So can you help me how to ignore this line or remove or compare it as string. tks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Use temp file to store value, in this case the newline will auto convert to "Echo..".
Output on temp file:

```
8589934592  
ECHO is off.
```